# Automatic data update & viualization

Tags: database, automation, data-visualization, visualization

this is my first post here so I hope i can describe my problem with enough details.
I have already searched for solutions, but could not figure out anythihg which really fits to my case.

What is the problem?
I am working at a producing company where we need to display the scheduled production orders so that the employees know which order they should produce next. At the moment we are realizing the planning with SAP and export the scheduling information afterwards into an excel-file.(At the moment it is a manual process, but we already pushed a change to automate this process also) Additionally we scrap some data from our sql-server, which includes additional data from SAP. (We use this step to have less effort to exctract the data we need) At the end we run a marco (programmed by me) which processes and aggregates the data to get the needed information for the other employees and to bring it into an appropriate format. The problem is now that we have to print out the planning every day (usually in the morning) physically and bring it to our employees. You can imagine that this is a lot of effort especially if there are any changes during the day.

What is needed?
I would like a solution, which automatically runs the macros in the excelfile (like every hour once) to scrap the needed data from the sql-server and updates something like a dashboard, where the empolyees can see, which production order is the next based on my scheduling. So my problem is that i neither know how the macro can be triggered automatically and furthermore I have no idea how we can visualize the scheduled orders in the production.

What have I tried already?

- PowerBI: Even if I could manage to extract the data automatically, it is not possible to visualize the production schedule as needed. The main problem here is that PowerBI does not support a row based conditional formatting. (Not without a enormous effort - it is not scalable) So I cannot display the schedule in an easy to interpret plan.
- Sharepoint: We already tried to export our schedule as pdf and to implement it on a sharepoint-side. This works but does not solve the problem with the automatic file update. Furthermore visualization of a pdf in a sharepointside is pretty suboptimal...
- Program an own webapplication to display the schedule. --> This is already in work but needs a lot of time due to the lack of knowledge which we have in our company. Furthermore we do not want to hire another company, because the main system (like SAP) do change based on the customer needs and we would lose the whole knowledge concerning the scheduling system out of hand. we also would like to be able to customize the system at short notice according to our needs.

Additional information:

- The excel-file needs to be edited by multiple persons during the day, so I cannot open       the file permanently on my computer or any other.
- The planning looks like a normal table with about 10 columns and about 50 - 100 rows (based on the amount of orders)

Programming skills:

- VBA
- SQL
- Powerquery M / DAX
- HTML / CSS / Javascript(basics)

Does anybody has a solution which can be implemented in short term to fix my problems?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards.